# Dovecot ignores settings for mailboxes

Tags: postfix, imap, dovecot, maildir

I have set up `Dovecot` on my `Postfix` mailserver. My mailserver is using `Maildir` format:

```
home_mailbox = Mail/inbox/
```

A user's Mail directory looks like this:

```
$HOME/Mail/inbox
$HOME/Mail/drafts
$HOME/Mail/sent
$HOME/Mail/trash
```

I have set up mailboxes in `Dovecot` accordingly

```
mail_location = maildir:~/Mail

namespace inbox {
  mailbox drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
}
```

Now, the problem is, `Dovecot` does not use the mailboxes as defined, but creates its own mailboxes named with a `.` in front and with first letter capital:

```
$HOME/Mail/.Drafts
$HOME/Mail/.Sent
$HOME/Mail/.Trash
```

Further, instead of using `$HOME/Mail/inbox` as `inbox`, it uses `$HOME/Mail` as inbox. i.e. it created the `cur/new/tmp` directories directly in `$HOME/Mail/`, rather than using the existing `$HOME/Mail/inbox`:

```
$HOME/Mail/cur
$HOME/Mail/new
$HOME/Mail/tmp
```

## SUMMARY:

explained briefly, what I need is the following:

I have an existing `Maildir` folder structure where `Postfix` delivers mail, plus the usual folders (`drafts`, `sent`, ...):

```
$HOME/Mail/inbox/{cur,new,tmp}
$HOME/Mail/drafts/{cur,new,tmp}
$HOME/Mail/sent/{cur,new,tmp}
$HOME/Mail/trash/{cur,new,tmp}
```

How can I tell `Dovecot` to use the correct directories?

Comment: It looks like you're mixing two things, the mapping between RFC 6154 tags and dovecot mailboxes and the mapping between dovecot mailboxes and filesystem directory names. Those are two different things.

Comment: @Pavel Šimerda - OK, thank you. Do you have a solution how to achieve what I need ?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to achieve. In my opinion the best way is to deliver mail always through Dovecot and then you don't have any problem. As a bonus, you can then use Dovecot's SIEVE filters which are really handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Dovecot uses Maildir++ directory layout for organizing mailbox directories. This means that all the folders are directly inside ~/Maildir directory, and:

```
~/Maildir/new, ~/Maildir/cur and ~/Maildir/tmp directories contain
the messages for INBOX.
```

You can read more about the layout [here](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailboxFormat/Maildir)

Thus what you complain about is standard behavior. You can change the layout nevertheless, by using the `LAYOUT` and `INBOX` options. To have `cur`, `new`, `tmp` inside `Inbox` as you require:

```
$HOME/Mail/inbox/{cur,new,tmp}
```

you could specify the following option in `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf`:

```
mail_location = maildir:~/Mail:INBOX=~/Mail/inbox:LAYOUT=fs
```

Comment: Good answer. But I still think it may be better to use dovecot's `deliver` to be able to make use of dovecot filtering features and stuff like that, as described in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Modify your `mail_location` as follows.

```
mail_location = maildir:~/Mail:LAYOUT=fs
```

Ref: [Dovecot Docs](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailboxFormat/Maildir)

- `~/Maildir/new`, `~/Maildir/cur` and `~/Maildir/tmp` directories contain the messages for `INBOX`.
- `~/Maildir/.folder/` is a mailbox `folder`
- You can also optionally use the `fs` layout by appending `:LAYOUT=fs` 
  to `mail_location`. This makes the folder structure look like: `~/Maildir/new`, `~/Maildir/cur` and `~/Maildir/tmp` directories contain the messages for `INBOX`, just like with `Maildir++`. `~/Maildir/folder/` is a mailbox folder

Comment: but I need `inbox` to be in `~/Maildir/inbox/new` not `~/Maildir/new`. Also, appending `:LAYOUT=fs` only changes the names of other folders from `.Draft` to `Draft`. But my folders have lower case letters, i.e. `draft`. Is there any way to configure this?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to work with dovecot maildirs is to always access them through tools packaged with dovecot. The combination of postfix and dovecot for virtual mailboxes follows.

This is not an answer to how to configure dovecot to understand postfix maildirs but rather an alternative way to work with e-mail directories. You can rather easily transition to this way by simply moving around the files so that everything resides where dovecot expects it.

/etc/postfix/master.cf

```
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}
```

/etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
virtual_transport = dovecot
virtual_mailbox_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual/domains
```

/etc/postfix/virtual/domains:

```
example.com    none
example.net    none
```

(Don't forget to run `postmap` on the file.)

/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf:

```
auth default {
    mechanisms = plain
    userdb static {
        args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/mail/%d/%n
    }
    passdb passwd-file {
        args = /etc/dovecot/passwd
    }
}
```

(Don't forget to create user `vmail` with group `vmail`.)

/etc/dovecot/passwd:

```
test@example.net:{PLAIN}yoursecretpassword
```

Of course all this is just a simple example (derived from an actual configuration), you can use any user backend you wish with any tools to manage it.

Answer (score 1):

for Dovecot 2.1+

```
namespace {
    type = private
    separator = .
    inbox = yes
  mailbox Trash {
    auto = subscribe # autocreate and autosubscribe
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  mailbox Drafts {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Junk
  }
}
```

You can also add your custom virtual mailboxes. Very nice docs can be found here:
http://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailboxSettings